# PHP GET and REQUEST are not working

Tags: php

I have a strange problem on a script php.

Using a search form I have categorie and city.

I get this using  var_dump($_REQUEST); or GET

```
array(4) {
    ["q"]=> string(0) ""
    ["categorie"]=> string(1) "2"
    ["city"]=> string(1) "1"
    ["PHPSESSID"]=> string(32) "81cce71a1ffe8e7793366b06e15225fc"
}
```

on my php code I have

```
$Categorie = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["categorie"]);
$City= mysql_real_escape_string($_GET["city"]);
```

also tried REQUEST

```
$Categorie = mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["categorie"]);
$City= mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["city"]);
```

But if I do

```
echo $Categorie; 
echo $City;
```

I don't get any result.

Is there any explanation for this?

Comment: Have you made your connection to mysql before calling mysql_real_escape_string?

Comment: Hi @JohnConde Yes, and using xampp on localhost works just fine, but on my server dont works. i m using mysqli connection

Comment: I didn't think mysqli worked with mysql_real_escape_string

Comment: If you're using MySQLi, then don't escape your inputs: use prepared statements/bind variable instead

Comment: It shouldn't matter if you use mysql or mysqli. Do you have show_errors turned on? Maybe you are surpressing some kind of notice/warning. Show us the entire code including the var_dump and echoes that return empty. I'm guessing your mysql library isn't installed/included, and the warning about it is being surpressed. You can off course also try mysql **i** _real_escape_string. http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

Comment: The problem was mysql_real_escape_string, i removed this and used a prepared statement and works fine.. thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Based on your comment, use mysql`i`, and it needs the link identifier:

```
$Categorie = mysqli_real_escape_string($your_link, $_GET["categorie"]);
$City= mysqli_real_escape_string($your_link, $_GET["city"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

From previous expierence, I have found that mysqli doesn't seem to work well with mysql_real_escape_string, have a look at using it like this:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php

I find mysql_real_escape_string to be outdated though

It states in the PHP manual that mysql_real_escape_string is deprecated

http://php.net/mysql_real_escape_string

It also gives suggestions what to use instead.

Answer (score 0):

Do `phpinfo();` and check if `mysql` is installed. Maybe you have only `mysqli` installed, but not `mysql` installed. That would cause `mysql_real_escape_string()` to not work. In that case you can try `mysqli_real_escape_string()` instead.